# How to install basemap in ocean parcels virtual environment

Tags: python

I am having a hard time installing basemap in the ocean parcels virtual environment. It looks like parcels was last updated with anaconda 2.3.0 and basemap is not in the installer. Has anyone else encountered and resolved how to use basemap while in the ocean parcels virtual environment?

Answer (score 0):

I used the following command:

```
python -m pip install basemap
```

It worked to fix this issue.